# Целесообразность метки [синтаксический-сахар]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, удаление-метки

На данный момент всего лишь 3 вопроса на основном сайте с подобной меткой [синтаксический-сахар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%b0%d1%80). Метка популярностью не пользуется, поэтому предлагаю ее убрать.

**P.S.** Если предложений больше не поступит, я сниму её (если никто не опередит) в течение 24 часов.

Comment: Не стоит сжигать метку, она не не противоречит [ни одному из критериев](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8/info).

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov  я, видимо, не правильно выразился) я хочу снять ее с 2 вопросов, а не удалять.

Comment: Я считаю, что в первых двух вопросах ее стоит убрать, в последнем (хрологически) - заменить на [tag:терминология]

Answer (score 2):

Вообще, странная метка, что у нас, что на [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntactic-sugar). Ну сахар и сахар. Я бы ещё понял, если бы там был какой-то теоретический вопрос, но, судя по тому, что я вижу, если выкинуть эту метку (привет, бритва Оккама), то ничего не изменится вообще.

Я бы просто снял эту метку с этих трёх вопросов, через месяц она сама сгорит, если никто использовать не будет.

P.S. метка исчезла (:

Comment: Метка слегка уточняет 1 вопрос, а на остальных 2, да, как-то ни на что и не влияет.

Comment: С другой стороны что делать тогда с первым вопросом, где речь идет о "сахаре" на 100%?

Comment: Да вроде неплохая метка, только расставить надо правильно.

Comment: @Qwertiy лепят часто не к месту. Но в целом да, сжигать не нужно. Если уж её не будут использовать, сама пропадёт.

Comment: Лично я поставил метку на свой [вопрос](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcIyc.png) т.к. она была на [аналогичном](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8aC4.png) на enSO.

Comment: Надо повторить с известной вам меткой это дело)